# How to Clone GitHub Repo to an IFS Directory instead of Local workspace for RPG Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, ibm-midrange, rpg, ibm-rational

Are there any direct/existing options to clone a Github repo into IFS repository either using VS code or RDi ?

We are tryin to create a development workflow where we plan to use GitHub for housing source code and then use IFS folders for each development branch for code compilation and testing in IBMi envt.

If Not , then what options should we explore to push the code from local workspace(Cloned from Github) to an IFS directory folder for development ?

Any assistance/feedback will be appreciated !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The IFS is a hierarchical file system much like the one used by Windows, or Linux. One of the easier ways to access it is through ssh, particularly if you want to use git because git, at least the version provided by IBM, needs to run in PASE. You should be able to install git and run it using ssh. To access the IFS libraries from VSCode, you need to set up shares. You can do that with i Access Client Solutions (iACS). Just so you don't get blindsided by it, PASE is based on one of those Unix's that only supports 8 character user ids, so if your IBM i user id is longer than 8 characters, you won't be able to log in to PASE with it. Gotta love that!

To find the git implementation supported by IBM, you are going to need to use the Open Source package management found in iACS.

Go ahead and Google how to do these things. That's what I would have to do to help you further. Apart from Google, you can find a lot of things in the IBM Knowledgebase here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5

Answer (score 0):

Inside of VS Code, you can upload your workspace (the clone repository on your machine) to the IFS using one of many extensions:

- SSH FS (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs)
- Code for IBM i (https://halcyon-tech.github.io/docs/#/pages/developing/local/getting-started)
- Any SFTP client